# Implementing your own Android bluetooth file transfer progress

Tags: android, bluetooth

Sending files over bluetooth in android is easy. I am fully aware of all the solutions about using in-built android system programs to handle the transfer.

But I've seen some apps that shows transfer progress bit by bit without system apps and I am wondering how can that be achieved?
With the normal Android Bluetooth API that is a bit restricted, I think.

I was googling, reading, browsing for countless hours but all I was able to find was to use intents and whatnot to send the file, which essentially uses system app to send files...

I tried coding with RFCOMM socket and I was able to write file bytes to the stream, but that didn't work as the other end didn't show it got a valid data stream and after some research there is a lot more to the protocol to initiate a proper transfer than just writing to the stream.

Comment: I think you can create a `BluetoothSocket` : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html

Comment: I tried that already and still no result.